# How to save log during uninstallation using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to log the uninstallation process, especially the files and folders deleted by `rmdir` for debug. However, `LogSet On` and [DumpLog](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Dump_log_to_file) function seems not working. Does anyone knows if there is a way to do it?

Edit:

I'm using DumpLog like:

```
Section "Uninstall"
;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...
  LogSet On
  DetailPrint "this is an uninstall test"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"  
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Test"
  DetailPrint "dumplog section"
  StrCpy $0 "$INSTDIR\install.log"
  Push $0
  Call un.DumpLog
SectionEnd

Function un.DumpLog
  Exch $5
  Push $0
  Push $1
  Push $2
  Push $3
  Push $4
  Push $6

  FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  GetDlgItem $0 $0 1016
  StrCmp $0 0 exit
  FileOpen $5 $5 a
  StrCmp $5 "" exit
    SendMessage $0 ${LVM_GETITEMCOUNT} 0 0 $6
    System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    Pop $3
    StrCpy $2 0
    System::Call "*(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i) i \
      (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, r3, ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) .r1"
    loop: StrCmp $2 $6 done
      System::Call "User32::SendMessageA(i, i, i, i) i \
        ($0, ${LVM_GETITEMTEXT}, $2, r1)"
      System::Call "*$3(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r4)"
      FileWrite $5 "$4$\r$\n"
      IntOp $2 $2 + 1
      Goto loop
    done:
      FileClose $5
      System::Free $1
      System::Free $3
  exit:
    Pop $6
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Pop $0
    Exch $5
FunctionEnd
```

More Edit:
Things are getting more complex.

I put the structure like:

```
-InstDir
 -UnInstDir
  -Uninstaller.exe
```

When I run uninstaller or use `execwait $InstDir\UnInstDir\Uninstall.exe`, `LogSet On` works and a new install.log was created in UnInstDir.

However, when I use `execwait $InstDir\UnInstDir\Uninstall.exe _?=$InstDir`, `LogSet On` doesn't work.

Anyone has any clue on it?

Comment: I recommend that you put your installer in the root of $instdir. $instdir in the uninstaller is just the directory the uninstaller is in. Only your installer (on upgrades) should use the _? = syntax, see https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new

Comment: It turns out that no matter where I put the uninstaller, `LogSet On` won't work as long as I use the _?=syntax. I think it does more than it says on [https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html)

Answer (score 0):

`LogSet` requires that you use [the logging build of NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Special_Builds). DumpLog only writes the same info as you see on the InstFiles page.

Another alternative is to [track the files as you install them](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Uninstall_only_installed_files).

The final option is to use `!system` to execute a script (batch file etc.) that generates two .nsh files (one for the installer, one for the uninstaller) with `File` and `Delete` instructions based on the output of `dir /s`.

Comment: I'm exactly trying to log what I see on the uninstall page. LogSet works fine in all install section but not working for uninstall section and FileOpen is not working when I call DumpLog. What do you think might be the issue?

Comment: The function is perhaps not suited for uninstallers. Do you get a compiler error message mentioning Un. functions? I'll try to update the wiki page in a couple of hours.

Comment: For `LogSet`, it's wired that it works for one uninstaller but not working for another with more codes.
For  `DumpLog`, it turns out for both installer and uninstaller, it can't work since  `FileOpen` always returns an empty string.
For both I don't see any error message occurs on the window or install.log

Comment: FileOpen will fail if it can't create the file (invalid path etc.) Could you please edit your question to include the code where you push and call DumpLog?

Comment: updated. btw I'm using the install.log, so it should be valid isn't it?

Comment: Your DumpLog code is a bit outdated, the one on the wiki is a little different. If LVM_GETITEMCOUNT and LVM_GETITEMTEXT are not defined correctly then it will not write anything but it should still be able to create a empty log file.

Comment: I used the one on wiki while it brought up an error during maknsis saying they are already defined